# How to configure KNIME/Weka to interact with my own software?

Tags: api, weka, knime

I have this task to bridge an analytics engine(like KNIME/Weka) to  a software. However, I am new to KNIME and APIs and most of CSE.
Could someone possibly guide me as to how do I bridge the softwares? A brief explaining KNIME APIs would be very helpful or any other tips for that matter.
Thanks !!

Comment: I would recommend using KNIME as a batch process (http://tech.knime.org/faq#q12) first, that way you can use it from any programming language (did you miss that information from your question?). If you want to use it with Java, I would suggest to get familiar with its license and the OSGi basics. (Obviously if you are using their Server product, you have other options too, like web services.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two links to use Weka from you Java code:

1. [Basic tutorial 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da6Iq2XV7_Q)
2. [Basic tutorial 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3Gf6kqaJWA)

I cannot say how to use knime as I am mostly familiar with Weka.